# How to select a given string repeatedly within the text of a contenteditable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have done a few hours of searching to answer this question, but I did not find any suitable answers, so I decided to try to write my own JQuery plugin to do the job.

These are the requirements:

- Select any string (i.e. 'abc') which is passed to the function from within the text that already resides in the contenteditable element.
- Selection should start with the first instance of that string within the element after the active caret position and move to the next instance of the same string the next time the function is called, regardless of whether the first selected instance was edited to something else (i.e. 'abc' was changed to 'xyz' by the user.
- String should be found in a text-node, not in an element-node or its attribute-nodes to allow for proper styling with classnames and references with ids.
- The entire string should be selected.
- The search should be limited to the contenteditable element only.

For example, if I have

```html
<div id='main' class='main' contenteditable>
    <p><span class='lead'>Date:</span>abc def abc 123 abc</p>
</div>
```

and I have the caret on "def" then run the function, the second "abc" should be selected.  If I don't move the caret and run the function again, the third "abc" should be selected.

Although the goals for my plugin are a little more extensive, I was surprised to find that there are no common solutions to even select a given string within a contenteditable div.

I will post a working version of my current JQuery plugin below.  Run the code snippet, place your caret inside the content-editable dive, and press F9 to run the function and select the text.  As you can see the solution is not very graceful and only works when the cursor is in certain locations.  I have to assume there is a more elegant solution, ideally even one that would accept RegEx's instead of strings.  I tried to make this work with recursion, but I couldn't find a way to reliably exit the recursive loop after the text-string was found.  Is there a better way?  I welcome your thoughts.

```js
document.getElementById('main').onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 120: {
            // F9 to select next %fill%
            $('#main').selecttarget('%fill%');
        }
    }
};

//JQuery plugin
jQuery.fn.selecttarget = function(target) {
    // get collection of all elements of the object passed (this)
    // de-jQuery into its DOM object by using this[0]
    var items = this[0].getElementsByTagName("*");

    // get the node at which the cursor currently resides
    var startNode = null;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        startNode = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
        startNode = (startNode.nodeType===1) ? startNode : startNode.parentNode;
    }

    // get the startNodes ancestry and iterate up through it until the passed element is found
    // once the passed element is found, we can step back down a level to find the ancestor
    // that is the immediate child of the passed element
    var parentEls = $(startNode).parents();
    var level = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < parentEls.length; i++) {
        if (parentEls[i] == this[0]) {
            level = i - 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    // the above method works somewhat well except if the caret is on the first span, then
    // it misses the first %fill%

    // get the index of the node at which the cursor currently resides amongst its siblings
    var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(items, parentEls[level]);

    // iterate through each child of the passed element looking for one that contains the
    // text we're looking for in target
    for (var i = index; i < items.length; i++) {
        var position = items[i].innerText.indexOf(target);

        if (position >= 0) {
            // if an appropriate element is found, iterate through
            // its child nodes to look for a text node with the
            // text we're looking for in target
            for (var j = 0; j < items[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
                var node = items[i].childNodes[j];
                if (node.nodeType == 3) {
                    position = node.data.indexOf(target);
                    if (position >= 0) {
                        // if a text node with the appropriate text
                        // is found, create a range and set its boundaries
                        var range = document.createRange()

                        range.setStart(node, position);
                        range.setEnd(node, position + target.length);

                        // create a selection based on the range
                        var sel = window.getSelection();
                        sel.removeAllRanges();
                        sel.addRange(range);

                        // exit everything
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

```css
div.main {
    text-align: left;
    width: 90%;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: scroll;
    border: solid thin cornflowerblue;
}
span.lineheader {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='main' class='main' contenteditable>
    <p><span class='lineheader'>Date:</span>&nbsp;%fill%</p>
    <p><span class='lineheader'>Item 1:</span>&nbsp;%fill%</p>
    <p><span class='lineheader'>Item 2:</span>&nbsp;%fill%</p>
    <p><span class='lineheader'>List 2:</span>
        <ul>
            <li>%fill%</li>
            <li>%fill%</li>
            <li>%fill%</li>
        </ul>
    </p>
    <p><span class='lineheader'>Item 2:</span>&nbsp;Sed convallis massa augue. Vivamus a enim vitae eros mattis dignissim ac non velit. Donec porta %fill% tellus in justo viverra rhoncus. Nullam et sapien dapibus, eleifend elit ac, commodo est. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vestibulum sagittis quis massa vitae bibendum. Maecenas placerat mi eget arcu aliquam, id %fill% accumsan nisi dictum.

Vestibulum consequat porttitor nisl eu ultrices. Donec non blandit tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse id ante et felis porttitor convallis. Sed.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more time researching this, I stumbled across Tim Down's Rangy JavaScript range and selection library (https://github.com/timdown/rangy).  This library turned out to be very helpful and was instrumental in finding the next occurrence of a string within all of a given element's child nodes.

First I used use conditional statements to handle the following possibilities of the selection/caret state upon an F9 keypress in the contenteditable element:

1. An instance of the search string is already selected
2. Something else is already selected, but not the selection doesn't match the search string
3. Nothing is selected, but the caret is at a position in the contenteditable element
4. The caret is not in the contenteditable element, but the contenteditable div has focus (i.e. user selected the scroll bar)

as below:

```
document.getElementById('main').onkeydown = function (e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 120: {
            // F9 to select next fill_me
            var sel = window.getSelection();

            // this should refer to document.getElementById('main')
            var target = 'fill_me';

            if (sel.toString().search(target) > -1) {
                // target is already selected; go to end of selection
                findOne(target, this, sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);
            }
            else if (sel.toString().length > 0) {
                // something is already selected but it's not target
                // so go to start of selection
                findOne(target, this, sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
            }
            else if (sel.rangeCount) {
                // nothing is selected, start search at cursor
                findOne(target, this, sel.anchorNode, sel.getRangeAt(0).endOffset);
            }
            else {
                // caret is not in the contenteditable element, but the contenteditable div has focus
                findOne(target, this, null, null);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

In each outcome above, the findOne function is called to find the appropriate instance of the search string, using Rangy's findText function:

```
function findOne(target, within, startNode, startPos) {
    if (rangy.supported) {
        var range = rangy.createRange();
        var searchScopeRange = rangy.createRange();
        var caseSensitive = true;

        // assign the search scope range to the contents of
        // the element passed as a parameter, within
        searchScopeRange.selectNodeContents(within);

        if (startNode != null && startPos != null) {
            // set the start of the search scope range if
            // passed parameters are not null; otherwise
            // its start is the beginning of  the range
            searchScopeRange.setStart(startNode, startPos);
        }

        var options = {
            caseSensitive: true,
            wholeWordsOnly: true,
            withinRange: searchScopeRange
        };

        range.selectNodeContents(within);

        if (target !== "") {
            target = new RegExp(target, caseSensitive ? "g" : "gi");

            // Find first match
            range.findText(target, options)

            // translate Rangy nodes & offsets to use for selection
            selectRange(range.startContainer, range.endContainer,
                        range.startOffset, range.endOffset);
        }
    }

    function selectRange(startNode, endNode, startPos, endPos) {
        // this function takes parameters and selects an appropriate
        // within the DOM
        var range = document.createRange()
        range.setStart(startNode, startPos);
        range.setEnd(endNode, endPos);

        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
}
```

The whole working project is included in the snippet below.  Thanks to Tim Down for his excellent work!

```js
rangy.init();

document.getElementById('main').focus();

document.getElementById('main').onkeydown = function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 120:
      {
        // F9 to select next %fill%
        //$('#main').selecttarget('%fill%');var node;
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        var target = 'fill_me';
        
        // this should refer to document.getElementById('main')
        if (sel.toString().search(target) > -1) {
          // target is already selected; go to end of selection
          findOne(target, this, sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);
        } else if (sel.toString().length > 0) {
          // something is already selected but it's not target
          // so go to start of selection
          findOne(target, this, sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
        } else if (sel.rangeCount) {
          // nothing is selected, start search at cursor
          findOne(target, this, sel.anchorNode, sel.getRangeAt(0).endOffset);
        } else {
          // this should never really happen, but it's a catch-all
          findOne(target, this, null, null);
        }
        break;
      }
  }
};

function findOne(target, within, startNode, startPos) {
  if (rangy.supported) {
    var range = rangy.createRange();
    var caseSensitive = true;
    var searchScopeRange = rangy.createRange();

    // assign the search scope range to the contents of
    // the element passed as a parameter, within
    searchScopeRange.selectNodeContents(within);

    if (startNode != null && startPos != null) {
      // set the start of the search scope range if
      // passed parameters are not null; otherwise
      // its start is the beginning of  the range
      searchScopeRange.setStart(startNode, startPos);
    }

    var options = {
      caseSensitive: true,
      wholeWordsOnly: true,
      withinRange: searchScopeRange
    };

    if (target !== "") {
      target = new RegExp(target, caseSensitive ? "g" : "gi");

      // Find first match
      range.findText(target, options)

      // translate Rangy nodes & offsets to use for selection
      selectRange(range.startContainer, range.endContainer,
        range.startOffset, range.endOffset);
    }
  }

  function selectRange(startNode, endNode, startPos, endPos) {
    // this function takes parameters and selects an appropriate
    // within the DOM
    var range = document.createRange()
    range.setStart(startNode, startPos);
    range.setEnd(endNode, endPos);

    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }

}
```

```css
div.main {
  text-align: left;
  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: solid thin cornflowerblue;
}
span.lineheader {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/currentrelease/rangy-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/currentrelease/rangy-textrange.js"></script>
<p><span class='lineheader'>Instructions:</span>&nbsp;Press F9 to skip between instances of <i>'fill_me'</i> in the contenteditable div below</p>
<div id='main' tabindex='0' class='main' contenteditable>
  <p><span class='lineheader'>Date:</span>&nbsp;fill_me.</p>
  <p><span class='lineheader'>Item 1:</span>&nbsp;fill_me</p>
  <p><span class='lineheader'>Item 2:</span>&nbsp;fill_me</p>
  <p><span class='lineheader'>List 1:</span>
    <ul>
      <li>fill_me</li>
      <li>fill_me</li>
      <li>fill_me</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
  <p><span class='lineheader'>Paragraph 1:</span>&nbsp;Sed convallis massa augue. Vivamus a enim vitae eros mattis dignissim ac non velit. Donec porta fill_me tellus in justo viverra rhoncus. Nullam et sapien dapibus, eleifend elit ac, commodo est. Vestibulum
    ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vestibulum sagittis quis massa vitae bibendum. Maecenas placerat mi eget arcu aliquam, id fill_me accumsan nisi dictum. Vestibulum consequat porttitor nisl eu ultrices. Donec
    non blandit tortor fill_me. Aliquam erat volutpat. fill_me id ante et felis porttitor convallis. Sed.</p>
</div>
```